# Laravel5 can't use package

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-5

I'm using L5(dev version) and trying to create package.
Doing `php artisan  workbench za-web/Sidebar --resources

It's creating for me structure and service provider.
[image]

And then I'm trying to add service provider to app/config.php

```
'ZaWeb\Sidebar\SidebarServiceProvider'
```

I've got the error:

```
    Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Class 'ZaWeb\Sidebar\SidebarServiceProvider' not found
```

Also was trying to do `composer dump-autoload`  but it doesn't helped.

Comment: Do you have the correct **PSR** mapping for that namespace?

Comment: in composer.json generated by artisan I have:
 "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src/migrations"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "ZaWeb\\Sidebar\\": "src/"
        }
    }

Comment: Also tried to do  "psr-4": {
            "ZaWeb\\Sidebar\\": "src/ZaWeb/Sidebar"
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out whats wrong, theres no autoload seciton for workmench directory in  **bootstrap/autoload.php**
I've add it and not everything ok.

```
if (is_dir($workbench = __DIR__.'/../workbench'))
{
    Illuminate\Workbench\Starter::start($workbench);
}
```